# not able to add new service in wcf. Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have created one service in WCF
When i tried to add another service i am getting this error

```
Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. 
Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.
```

The other service is running properly, but i get the error only when i run the new service

This is my web.config

```
 <services>
      <service name="namespace.CreateCompetition">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="namespace.ICreateCompetition" />
      </service>
      <service name="namespace.ProblemStatement">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="namespace.IProblemStatement"/>
      </service>
    </services>
```

When i run the solution outside of ProblemStatement.svc its not even showing this service
Only the CreateCompetition.svc is listed

Comment: I notice you are using Https for the working service. The other one is configured for metadata over plain http. Maybe your infrastructure does not allow http only?

Comment: I tried changing that one too !! But its not working